# Python win32com.client - Email only goes out when I have outlook open

Tags: python, winapi, win32com

I currently have a python script which I'm trying to automate to send an email out via my account. I'm using the win23com.client library to do this, and really briefly this is what my code is doing:

```
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = (list of emails)
#mail.cc = x
mail.Subject = x
mail.HTMLBody = (python object with HTML code)
mail.Send()
```

When I run the above with Outlook closed, I get the following error code:

```
com_error: (-2147467260, 'Operation aborted', None, None)
```

However if I run it with Outlook open it sends it out fine through my email account. I'm guessing it must have an issue in authenticating my account with outlook closed, but my colleagues don't seem to be having the same issue on the same network.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
message = 'Hello'
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'email'
mail.Subject = 'This is a test'
mail.HTMLBody = message
mail.Send()
```

Check this. It works for me even with Outlook closed.